# How to grab first ip address from a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to grab an `ip address` from a string and facing an issue.please help.
`inet addr:11.11.11.11  Bcast:11.11.11.111  Mask:111.111.11.1`.
This is the string I have and I need ip address next to addr:

I have tried the following code and failed to do in python:

`ip = re.findall(r'(?:\d{1,3}\.)+(?:\d{1,3})', line)` and get index 0 item.

Result : This is actually giving me nothing in return

Comment: Try prepending addr and use a capturing group `addr:((?:\d{1,3}\.)+(?:\d{1,3}))` https://ideone.com/8qUHqL

Comment: Your code works well and gives proper results. Try this `import re

line = 'inet addr:11.11.11.11  Bcast:11.11.11.111  Mask:111.111.11.1'
ip = re.findall(r'(?:\d{1,3}\.)+(?:\d{1,3})', line)
print(ip[0])`

Comment: I checked in editor and I see I get results but when I run test I do not see any result

Comment: Show your code that fails.

Comment: I found my mistake. I was checking it for every line and since the first line doesn't have it returns false and comes out of the loop. Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your REGEX could be more specific, I think you could use something like :

`addr:(?<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})`

In python:

`match = re.match(r'addr:(?<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})', line)`

You can then access the `ip` group by calling `match.group('ip')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

line = "inet addr:11.11.11.11  Bcast:11.11.11.111  Mask:111.111.11.1"

pattern = r"[\d]{2}[.][\d]{2}[.][\d]{2}[.][\d]{2}[\D]"

re.findall(pattern, line)
```

`['11.11.11.11 ']`

```
re.findall(pattern, line)[0].strip()
```

`'11.11.11.11'`

if you have more than one element in the list just run a list-comp using `.strip()`

```
[i.strip() for i in re.findall(pattern, line)]
```

`['11.11.11.11']`

`re.match()` is not going to work because it will try to match your pattern starting at the beginning of the string (granted that your pattern does not include the "**inet addr:**" portion.
`re.search()` works but it misses recurring elements and only returns the first encounter of the pattern upon a successful match, in addition you'll have to use `filter` to extract the element.

finally, the key to solving this problem lies in the last character of your target, `xx.xx.xx.xx[\D]`. The `[\D]` directive ensures that the pattern looks for a no-integer at index 12, `[\s]` works equally well and it matches a space.